# Font-family looks all the same / doesn't work - android

Tags: android, android-layout

i'd like to understand how to control the font-family. 
Even though iv'e explicitly given a different font for each tag - ALL LOOKS THE SAME. 
but when i open the .otf file - its does differ one from another.

font family-

[image: font family]

assistant-light -

[image: assistant_light]

Comment: Have you checked it after run on the real device or emulator?

Comment: checked - doesnt work on real device